# What are the limits on the number of vertex groups that can be assigned in an object?

Tags: modeling, vertex-groups

A question about the maximum number of characters that can be used in a name led me to wonder about limits on other things in Blender. So, what is the maximum number of vertex groups that can be applied to a single object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assigned 513 different vertex group slots to a single cube. If there is a limit (other than the size of the available memory), this suggests at least 66536 separate groups.